# Mocking final static void method using powermock and return some values based on the arguments

Tags: java, powermockito

I was trying to mock a final static void method inside a final class. I want to return some values using the arguments in my final method.
I am using powermockito. can anyone tell me how we can mock a final static void method and return some value as I mentioned above.

```
final class

public final class myFinalClass{

   public final static void myMethod(String s, String val) {

   }
}
```

Comment: How come void method returns value...

Comment: yeah!!..But I need that values in the argument to test something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerMockito can be used for both mocking and verifying static methods.

**How to Mock:**

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStaticMethods.class) 
PowerMockito.when(ClassWithStaticMethods.staticMethodCall()).thenReturn (obj1);
```

**How to verify:**

```
PowerMockotio.verifystatic(Mockito.times(1));
ClassWithStaticMethods.staticMethodCall();
```